# SQL Server Managemet Studio not finding local server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Here I think my local machine should be shown. But it is not shown. So I can't connect to it. What is the solution for this?

[image]

Comment: type localhost and then try ?

Comment: got a error message when type localhost

Comment: Well, have you installed the SQL Server **core** (engine) on your local machine - or did you install only the management studio ?!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager` and see that your SQL Server service is installed, up and running and what it's name is:

[image]

- if you **don't find** any entry under "SQL Server Services" that looks like `SQL Server (instancename)`, then you don't have SQL Server (the engine, the core) installed
- if you find a value of `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` in your list and it's in `State = Running`, you should be able to connect to it using `.`, `(local)`, or `your-machine-name` as the server/instance name
- if you find any other value (like `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` in my example), then you have a **named instance** and you can connect to it using `.\instance-name`, `(local)\instance-name` - e.g. `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` in this case

Comment: There is no items under SQL server services. So I think I have to reinstall SQL server. right??

Comment: @user3888646: well, you probably never installed the core engine of SQL Server ... what **exactly** did you install? Which file did you download from Microsoft?

Comment: SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU is the setup file. But this same setup works fine in my desktop PC without a problem.I didn't install any other file in that pc. This problem comes only in laptop.

Comment: That is ***only*** the Management Studio - the GUI - but that does ***not contain*** the actual SQL Server core engine - you need to get and install that, too!!

Answer (score -2):

On Browse for servers window.Click on the Network Server.You can find your Local server.

I think this should work.